# CCAvenue Payment Gateway in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, flutter-dependencies

I need to do the payment gateway integration for ccAvenue. Flutter has the dependency of Razorpay, Paytm etc. But it has no dependency on ccAvenue. How to open ccAvenue gateway for my flutter application?

Comment: Why not use Razorpay instead. We have a well-tested sdk for Flutter.https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/flutter-integration/

Comment: No, it's a client requirement. client not changing the payment gateway as we asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this package [cc_avenue](https://pub.dev/packages/cc_avenue)

```
CcAvenue.cCAvenueInit(
    transUrl: 'https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/initTrans',
    accessCode: '4YRUXLSRO20O8NIH',
    amount: '10',
    cancelUrl: 'http://122.182.6.216/merchant/ccavResponseHandler.jsp',
    currencyType: 'INR',
    merchantId: '2',
    orderId: '519',
    redirectUrl: 'http://122.182.6.216/merchant/ccavResponseHandler.jsp',
    rsaKeyUrl: 'https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/jsp/GetRSA.jsp'
  );
```

Comment: This package is only available for Android. Still iOS development is pending.